# Return certain value if ListView successfully renders

Tags: android, listview

Here's some pseudo java code to describe my problem: Basically I want to return a different view (ViewGood or ViewEmpty) depending on whether `getView()` in my adapter successfully returns a view. However, as far as I understand it, the `setAdapter()` function call will run asynchronously and the ListView will render sometime in the future so immediately after the `setAdapter()` call I won't know whether to return `ViewGood` or `ViewEmpty`. Does anyone have a solution to this?

```
public class MyFragment {
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public onCreateView() {
        boolean atLeastOneViewLoaded = false;
        mListView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
        if (atLeastOneViewLoaded) {
            return ViewGood;
        } else {
            return ViewEmpty;
        }
    }
}


public class MyAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        // if at least one view returns here successfully, then I want to 
        // return ViewGood, otherwise return ViewEmpty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface. Just pass in an instance in your adapters constructor.

```
            public class MyAdapter {
private ActivityAdapterListener mListener;
private ArrayList<Pojo> myArray;

public MyAdapter (ArrayList<YourPojo> yourArray, ActivityAdapterListener listener){
this.mListener = listener;
this.myArray = yourArray;
    }
}

   @Override
public View getView(int position) {
    // if at least one view returns here successfully, then I want to 
    // return ViewGood, otherwise return ViewEmpty
Pojo pojo = getItem(position);
if(position > 0)
{
listener.onSuccess();
}

}
```

I've not tested the above but it should give you an idea.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the statement `if (atLeastOneViewLoaded){}` would have finished executing by the time{}``listener.onSuccess()` is called so I can't return the correct value.

Comment: If I understand you approach correctly you want to show a certain view if you have an empty list? In which case would a ListFragment be useful to you? You can specify an alternative view to be show if you list is empty. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html